# oh-my-zsh custom plugin autocomplete files and dirs

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've extended the laravel 5plugin like this:

```
# Laravel5 basic command completion
_laravel5_get_command_list () {
    php artisan --no-ansi | sed "1,/Available commands/d" | awk '/^ +[a-z]+/ { 
    print $1 }'
}

_laravel5 () {
  if [ -f artisan ]; then
    compadd `_laravel5_get_command_list`
  fi
}

compdef _laravel5 artisan
compdef _laravel5 la5
compdef _laravel5 art

#Alias
alias la5='php artisan'
alias art='php artisan'

alias la5cache='php artisan cache:clear'
alias la5routes='php artisan route:list'
alias la5vendor='php artisan vendor:publish'
```

When I start using in, I want in the end to **autocomplete with files from my disk**.
Example:

```
artisan custom:import **<filename>**
```

**The tab autocompletion works with 'art', 'custom', 'import' but in the end, if I type ~ do start choosing a file from my homedir, it doesn't autocomplete.**

What am I missing?